# Unable to install magento 2 again with composer Exception

Tags: composer-php, magento2

Good evening, I am having some trouble updating a package to the last version, currently I have :
"ingenico/m2-payment": "^2.2",
"ingenico/ogone-client": "^5.0",

I need to update to lates version of m2-payment, but when applying the solution in the update section (both with zip and non zip) I get the following :

```
[Exception]                                                                                                                                   
  Higher matching version 2.11.0 of ingenico/m2-payment was found in public repository packagist.org                                            
                               than 2.5.2 in private https://repo.magento.com. Public package might've been taken over by a malicious entity,   
                               please investigate and update package requirement to match the version from the private repository
```

In our producction mode we have the composer.lock in our repository so we just do composer install --no-dev

But now I cant even install magento if I delete vendor and execute the composer install --no-dev, it shows the same error again.

I can solve this by adding the --no-plugins flag but it is not good because our producctions those not included that command when deploying

Comment: What is the version of igencio/m2-payment you need to update to?

Comment: latest (2.11.0)

Comment: Require that version in your composer.json.

Comment: it is required and still nothing, same issue

Comment: Now update the private repository to provide that version.

Comment: I finally figure it out, will reply

Comment: yikes, I didn't thought about the package exclusion in the repository definition. you have my upvote.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply exclude the package in the `composer.json` from repo.magento so it downloads it from packagist :

```
"magento": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com",
            "exclude": ["ingenico/m2-payment"]
        },
```

Compare [*Filtering packages*](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/repository-priorities.md#filtering-packages).

I also have Composer version 2.